# Cycle through array with animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

So I want to cycle through a list of arrays when I click the button, I've found info but can't figure out how and where to put it into the code I have already, check the below to see what I have already;

[My Current Code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqKYwz)

```
[1]: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqKYwz
```

If anyone could help me out that'd be great! It'd be a bonus if someone could show me how to style the Launch link, for some reason its being annoying as hell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by cycle you mean to display all the name of the games one by one before displaying the final name of the game here is what you can do,

[**Here is a demo**](http://codepen.io/saumil11/pen/OVjLRW)

So I have altered the `PickRandomWord()` and `tick()` and created 2 global variables "i" and "s" as below,

```
var i = 0;
var s;

function PickRandomWord(frm) {
        s = setInterval(function() {
            tick(frm);
        }, 180);
    }
function tick(frm) {

    frm.WordBox.value = words[i+1];
    i++;
    if (i > 27) {
        clearInterval(s);
        var rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random() * NumberOfWords);

        var index = words[rnd].indexOf("/");

        frm.WordBox.value = words[rnd].substring(0, index);
        var link = document.getElementById("gameLink");
        var str = words[rnd].substring(index + 1, words[rnd].length);
        link.innerHTML = "<a class='launchLink' href ='steam://run/" + str + "'>Launch</a>";
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

As you requested I have created a class `launchLink` for your "Launch" button and have applied some simple styling. You can change the styling according to your preferences.

Comment: @user5006419 does this answer your question?

Comment: Is there a way to make it to slowly stop after 5 seconds or rather than constantly cycling through them? I've looked for a few solutions but cannot find one.

Comment: @user5006419 If you want the cycling for 5 seconds then you can change the setInterval() timings from 100 to 180. Check my updated answer and updated demo.